# generate epub using python by newbie

Tags: python, epub

As my first project for python coding, I want to create epub file from articles in journals like BMJ using python.

I extract links from [BMJ](http://www.bmj.com/specialties/7/all-bmj/feed?list=all-bmj) RSS using `feedparser`, used the `beautifulsoup` to capture the component in the html file that I need, then I follow the instruction from the [link](http://www.manuel-strehl.de/dev/simple_epub_ebooks_with_python.en.html) to create a epub file.

EPUB file can be created, but not some epub reader consider the file corrupted, for example the coolreader for both windows and android show nothing, while the android version even exit the program unexpectedly.

I guess some of the "declaration" for epub is not right that cause this problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

I have some coding experience in R and did some web scraping using the `XML` package, but no experience in EPUB format.

Comment: Try using EpubLib it's easy and good https://pypi.org/project/EbookLib/

Answer (score 2):

Try running epubcheck on your book. That what it's for. See https://code.google.com/p/epubcheck/. The most recent versions are remarkably detailed. It is hard to imagine an e-reader which would choke on a book that passed epubcheck. Or, to put it another way, if an e-reader chokes on a book that passed epubcheck, then it's probably a bug in the e-reader.

You may also want to check out https://code.google.com/p/python-epub-builder/. I doubt if it will create broken epubs.

Answer (score 0):

In `calibre`'s conversion settings, there is a setting to split source file into pages (multiple small html file within the same epub archive) by 280kb. IIRC, it says many  ebook readers can not handle html that is too big, should be split into  smaller files. Maybe you could should check that field constraint.